# Google Drive, Service Account: Can I further restrict permissions per file/folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am building an application where I'd like to enable collaboration using drive/RT api.  I have setup a service account so that any shared files are stored in my application account, and some server code that will get you a JWT token if you are an authorized user of the application.  All good.

The question I have is I'd like to prevent application user "Bob" from being able to access application data that belongs to application user "Larry".  Once you have the service account token you have access to all data thats in my application drive.  Is there any way to further restrict access on a file or folder?

The best I can come up with so far is create a seperate "project" for each application user with it's own service account, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Note:  I am using service account because not every user of my application would have a google account.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what service account always do since it's an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts). Also, I've read [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) that *"For example, a policy set in the Google Apps Admin console to restrict the ability of Apps end users to share documents outside of the domain would not apply to service accounts."*. You may check on this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989111/how-do-i-restrict-a-google-service-account) which might help.